# Android : Google play console app update rejected due to policy violation : All Files Access Permission

Tags: android, google-play-console, mediastore, scoped-storage, privacy-policy

Google play console app update rejected due to policy violation : All Files Access Permission

We are facing an issue with the current Google privacy policy. We have uploaded the app on Playstore with latest Target SDK version 30. We have made changes accroding to this documentation  [Meet Google Play's target API level requirement](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk). We have gone through with this  [Use of All files access Permisson](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955?visit_id=1637411472053-4709241375886528054&rd=1) document as well. We are using MediaStore API to access shared storage. Not used MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE anywhere in the app and also checked in third-party libraries. But still google is rejecting app with same reason.

[image: Issue : Not a code feature]

[image: Issue : Need to use Media Store API or no Access to File]

Can someone help me with that?

Note: I have also raised appeal in google play support to get exact reason for that. but don't have enough time to wait for it. If someone faced same issue and issue resolved. it will be great clue for us to get this resolved.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello. Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: did you solved this issue?

Comment: @D.madushanka, issue is solved by adding the release apk in all the channels. like in internal testing, open testing, closed testing and production

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps:
I recently had a user making me aware that my app's manifest was showing all sorts of permissions that were totally irrelevant for the app. Turns out these permissions get added by libraries etc during compiling. I used an app callled apk explorer which shows the manifest content as they are in the apk. In my case adding the following to the manifest resolved the issue and these no longer show up

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

Comment: Theo, you were also getting the rejection reason from Google Play for the app?

Comment: No I wasn't but still thought it might be relevant